# IOS: Ambiguous Use of init(CGImage)

Tags: swift, cgimage, ciimage

I am trying to convert a `CGImage` into a `CIImage`; however, it is not working.

This line of code:

```
let personciImage = CIImage(CGImage: imageView.image!.CGImage!)
```

throws the following error

> Ambiguous use of 'init(CGImage)'

I'm really confused as to what this error means.

I need to do this conversion because `CIDetector.featuresInImage()` from the built in `CoreImage` framework requires a `CIImage`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I solved it on my own.

It turns out, I was capitalizing CGImage wrong. The code should really read:

```
let personciImage = CIImage(cgImage: imageView.image!.cgImage!)
```

This throws no errors.

Comment: seems to be an artifact of conversion between Swift versions. Why would the compiler not flag this as an unknown?

Comment: I was stuck on this for a bit. Thank you.