# Ambiguous use of 'init'

Tags: swift

I try to initial my class with block (closure) but I got

> Ambiguous use of 'init'

[image]

all the time, my class in objective c and I try to use it in swift4

Objc init

```
typedef void (^updateCoordinate)(CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate);

- (instancetype)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate Dragable:(BOOL)isDragable updateCoordinate:(updateCoordinate)updateCoordinate;
```

Swift init

```
let map = FAMapViewController.init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0, 0), dragable: true) { (coordinate) in  }
```

`NS_SWIFT_NAME` does not help me, I got same issue any advice Please .

Comment: `CLLocationCoordinate2DMake`? What version of Swift is this??

Comment: I'm using #import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h> @Alexander

Comment: What auto completion options do you get when you type `FAMapViewController.init`?

Comment: @Fogmeister screenshot was written below , under "Swift init"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for my issue , I use same method name with deferent parameter in Objective-C Class

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
     Dragable:(BOOL)isDragable 
    updateCoordinate:(updateCoordinate)updateCoordinate;
```

and

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
 Dragable:(BOOL)isDragable;
```

> just used `NS_SWIFT_NAME` to change names and it's work fine

```
NS_SWIFT_NAME(init(withUpdateCoordinateAndCoordinate:isDragable:withUpdateCoordinate:));
```

and

```
NS_SWIFT_NAME(init(withCoordinate:isDragable:));
```

Answer (score 2):

`Ambiguous use of 'init'` means the signature of the `init` call you're making in your Swift can't be matched to an `init` in the target class.

I've seen this error caused by simple mistakes in the call site - like capitalisation being incorrect. For example in your Swift `init` call you have a lowercase `dragable: true` but in the Objc init you have `Dragable:(BOOL)`

StackOverflow is full of examples of incorrect capitalisation, e.g.:

[IOS: Ambiguous Use of init(CGImage)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45177678/ios-ambiguous-use-of-initcgimage)

[SCNSceneSource init is giving Ambiguous use of 'init(URL:options:)' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46219466/scnscenesource-init-is-giving-ambiguous-use-of-initurloptions-error)

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, you need to check the DUPLICATE of the `init` function in your `class` or `struct`. This example will be showing error `Ambiguous use of 'init'`

```
init(name: String = "") { 
    self.id = -1
    self.name = name
}

init(id: Int = -1, name: String = "") {
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
}
```